# Fancybox not opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

for some reason my fancy box does not show up when clicking on the hyperlink (the page just moves up a few pixels), see
http://goo.gl/n6df2y (haven't been able to reproduce that in jsfiddle).
Any idea what the issue is?
Many thanks,

HTML

```
  <div class="inscription-newsletter"><p><b>Restez informés!</b> Inscrivez-vous à la <a class="fancybox" href="#newsletterpopup">newsletter</a></p></div>

<div id="newsletterpopup">
      <h1>Inscription à la Newsletter</h1>
      <p>Inscrivez-vous à la newsletter pour être tenu au courant des nouveautés du site et de l'agenda des conférences</p>
      <div class="message"></div>
      <form role="form" class="form-newsletter" method="post" id="subscribe">
        <input type="email" class="newsletter-field" id="newsletteremail" name="email" placeholder="e-mail" value="">
        <button type="submit" class="newsletter-button" id="newslettersubmit">OK</button>
      </form>
      <div class="non-merci"><b>X</b> FERMER</div>
      <div class="max-emails">Pas de spam ici :-) Maximum 1 e-mail envoyé par mois!</div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
//==============
//! Fancybox and cookie
//==============

function openFancybox() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".fancybox").trigger("click");
    }, 7000);
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        return false;
    } else {
        openFancybox();
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', {
        expires: 0.04
    });
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        closeClick: false,
        showCloseButton: true,
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                css: {
                    'background': 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.3)'
                }
            }
        },
        afterShow: function () {
            // enables a way to close fancybox
            $(".non-merci").on("click", function () {
                $.fancybox.close()
            });
        }
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready


//==============
//! 
//==============


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#subscribe').submit(function() {
        if (!valid_email_address($("#newsletteremail").val()))
        {
            $(".message").html("<span style='color:red; margin-bottom: 3px;'>Email non valide</span>");
        }
        else
        {

            $(".message").html("<span style='color:green;'>En cours d'ajout...</span>");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'subscribe.php', 
                data: $('#subscribe').serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(msg) {
                    if(msg=="success")
                    {
                        $("#newsletteremail").val("");
                        $(".message").html('<span style="color:green;">E-mail ajouté avec succès. Merci!</span>');
                        setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 2000);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                      $(".message").html('E-mail non valide');  
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
function valid_email_address(email)
{
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);
    return pattern.test(email);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check your code, because the popup is showing the first time.
In the other visits 'visited == 'yes' the 'return false' will stop executing the function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        return false;
    } else {
        openFancybox();
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', {
        expires: 0.04
    });
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({...
```

Try to remove the return:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited != 'yes'){
        openFancybox();
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', {
        expires: 0.04
    });
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // API options
    });
});
```

Comment: not really, the cookie only avoids to fire fancybox programmatically after the first time visit (the OP shouldn't remove `return false;`), but the visitor should be able to open the fancybox manually through a link http://jsfiddle.net/SKh9e/

Comment: The cookie doesn't work in the jsfiddle. If you change the if to "if ('yes' == 'yes')" you will see.

Comment: +1 : My mistake, the original code from the OP (in another question) was using the cookie to show fancybox once on page load. Then he requested to show fancybox once on page load via cookie AND to have the link to optionally open fancybox manually ... and I guess I overlooked the cookie would void the fancybox initialization on the second page load. Good catch.

Answer (score -3):

I assume you're talking about:  http://fancybox.net/howto

You are supposed to do a $(".newsletterpopup").fancybox() to get it to show up.